# Will the ''wipe data/factory reset'' in ClockworkMod also remove my backups I have done?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, factory-reset

I currently have CyanogenMod 10.1 (Android 4.2.1) on my Galaxy SIII. I used ClockworkMod to flash the ROM.

Now, after using the ROM for a while, I want to try some other ROMs, so I made a backup of my current ROM (CyanogenMod 10.1) in ClockworkMod recovery and the backup was saved to: `/mnt/shell/emulated/clockworkmod/backup`.

Now, if I use the "wipe data/factory reset" option in ClockworkMod recovery, will that remove the backup I made?

Comment: There is fairly detailed documentation http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-clockworkmod-recovery-and-how-to-use-it-on-android-complete-guide/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Wipe data* will wipe everything on your `/data` partition (hence the name). A *factory reset* will wipe the same (additionally also cache and Dalvik cache), and put your device back to a virgin state. Usually, this doesn't touch the (external) SDCard, and AFAIK should not touch the internal SDCard either.

I don't know on which partition your mentioned folder resides; but if you want to be on the safe side, back up everything to the external SDCard (or even better off-device, e.g. to your computer).

Comment: On the Nexus 5 the `clockworkmod` backup folder hides under `data/media`  and I can confirm that this does not get wiped by the `factory reset/data wipe` option. Ditto for backups created with the oandbackup app

Answer (score 0):

It deletes `/data` files. If you have a backup in `mnt/shell`, it will not be deleated. Also, you can restore your backup after factory reset.